# ng-repeat just doesnt work

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

```
        <div ng-init="offers = [
                     {state:'Zabiorę', from:'Warszawa', to:'Wrocław', date:'30/04/16', size:'S:8 M:4 L:2 XL:0'},
                     {state:'Wyśle', from:'Wrocław', to:'Warszawa', date:'31/04/16', size:'S:0 M:1 L:0 XL:0'}]">

        <div ng-repeat="offer in offers">
            <hr class="featurette-divider">
            <div class="announcement row">
                <div class="col-md-1"><strong>{{offer.state}}</strong></div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img class="img-circle"
                         src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
                         alt="Generic placeholder image" width="70" height="70">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">{{offer.from}}</div>
                <div class="col-md-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
                <div class="col-md-1">{{offer.to}}</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">{{offer.date}}</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">{{offer.size}}</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Szczegóły</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div> // </div ng-cloak>
```

Hello, i just wrote some code in my jhipster project, i wrote that in one of my project template and it just doesnt work, it shows nothing. When on jsfiddle.net it works.

@edit

Entire code, controller and state:

```
 - http://pastebin.com/2tkvbiwG - template.html 
 - http://pastebin.com/kV4E7x0G - state.js
 - http://pastebin.com/XF5rBmK7 - controller.js
```

Comment: Have you added in your project the reference for angularjs.js? If on jsfiddle is working, it means you have some problems with references

Comment: It doesnt it, if delete reference to script u see something like {{offer.*}} ect. But is see nothing on my page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work just fine. Please check that you have included angular.js and that you have defined your `ng-app` and `ng-controller`

Here is a plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/JLIQJQoEM9q4iAztY7KQ?p=preview

## EDIT

In controller.js you need to define ui-router like this.

```
 angular
        .module('deliveritApp', ['ui.router'])
        .controller('SearchOfferController', SearchOfferController);
```

Also name your `function SearchController` to `function SearchOfferController`.

In state.js you need to add the `$stateProvider` in the config like this:

```
 angular
        .module('deliveritApp')
        .config(['$stateProvider', stateConfig])
```

Comment: Exactly,assuming you have only 1 module, in html tag insert `ng-app` and in div or body (depending if you have 1 or more) insert `ng-controller` + name of controller

Comment: its not this, its something with session data

Comment: @ulou Could you please provide the full html

Comment: @Konkko http://pastebin.com/2tkvbiwG - template.html 
http://pastebin.com/kV4E7x0G - state.js
http://pastebin.com/XF5rBmK7 - controller.js

Comment: "Also name your function SearchController to function SearchOfferController." fixed my problem